# How get full path to target of link

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, bash-scripting

If I have a symbolic link `/var/opt/foo` created with `ln -fs /path/to/target/dir foo`. How can I in a script that sees only the link get `/path/to/target/dir`?

What I want to achieve in the script is `rm -rf /path/to/target/dir` before I do `ln -fs /path/to/another/dir foo`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
link=/var/opt/foo

target=$(readlink "$link")
```

`$target` is now the target of the link, exactly as it was stored in the filesystem.

Symlinks can be relative, though, so this would be better for normal usage:

```
target=$(readlink -f "$link")
```

Note that this uses `readlink` from GNU Coreutils, which may not exist in BSD and other systems.

*Edit:* `readlink -f` works on BSDs, as long as the link target exists. `realpath` is another, BSD-only, tool that works in a similar way.

Comment: The BSDs have had a `readlink()` system call since the days of 4.2BSD.  The current BSDs' `readlink` _utility_ was released with FreeBSD 4.10.  It was (re)implemented as a hard link for the `stat` command ([MacOS X manual page](http://developer.apple.com./library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/readlink.1.html) [FreeBSD 9 manual page](http://freebsd.org./cgi/man.cgi?query=readlink&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9-current)).  Notice that it doesn't have a `-m` option.

Comment: @JdeBP: Thanks. It does have `-f`, and `readlink -f` works just as well (assuming the link target exists). In BSD, `realpath` appears to be another alternative to `readlink -m`.

Answer (score 1):

This `abspath()` function should work for both Linux and BSD/OSX, including if you don't have GNU coreutils installed via homebrew.

Using this mechanism I would do something like this to solve your example:

```
f="$(abspath /path/to/target/dir)" && rm -rf "$f"
```

and here's my implementation of cross platform abspath:

```
function _abspath_the_hard_way ()
{ # See _abspath() for the rest of an implementation of something like GNU's `readlink -f`.
  # assumes running under bash
  # $1     : absolute or relative filename
  # return : absolute path, sort of

  local bn
  bn="$(readlink "$1")"
  if [ $? -ne 0 ] # if is not a symlink
  then
    bn="$(basename "$1")"
  else
    if [ -z "${bn%%/*}" ] # if linked-to starts with a /
    then
      echo "$bn"
      return
    fi
  fi

  if [ -d "$1" ]
  then
    (cd "$1" && pwd -P )
    return
  elif [[ $1 == /*/* ]]
  then
    echo "$(cd "${1%/*}" && pwd -P)/${bn}"
    return
  elif [[ $1 == /* ]]
  then
    echo "/$bn"
    return
  elif [[ $1 == ./* ]]
  then
    echo "$(pwd -P)/$bn"
    return
  elif [[ $1 == */* ]]
  then
    echo "$(cd "${1%/*}" && pwd -P)/$bn"
    return
  else
    echo "$(pwd -P)/$bn"
    return
  fi

  false
}

function _abspath ()
{
  local x="$(sed -r 's,//+,/,g ; s,/[.]/,/,g' <<<"$1" )"
  local y="$(_abspath_the_hard_way "$x" | sed -r 's,//+,/,g ; s,/[.]/,/,g' )"
  while [ "$x" != "$y" ]
  do
    x="$(sed -r 's,//+,/,g ; s,/[.]/,/,g' <<<"$y" )"
    y="$(_abspath_the_hard_way "$x")"
  done
  echo "$y"
}


_abspath_mechanism=  # optimize to detect underlying mechanism only once
function abspath ()
{ # like `readlink -f` but should work on BSD, more or less
  # $1     : relative filename
  # return : absolute path
  #   See description of -f in GNU's readlink(1).
  #   Returns false if it can't resolve the path, true otherwise.
  #   It can return an empty string along with false.

  case "$_abspath_mechanism" in
  (readlink_f) readlink -f "$1" ; return ;;
  (greadlink_f) greadlink -f "$1" ; return ;;
  (_abspath) _abspath "$1" ; return ;;
  esac

  # Best is to simply call GNU's `readlink -f` if it's available.
  if [ "$(uname -s)" = Linux ]
  then
    _abspath_mechanism=readlink_f
    readlink -f "$1"
    return
  elif type greadlink >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
    # This is for if you're running OSX and have installed coreutils utilities via homebrew.
    _abspath_mechanism=greadlink_f
    greadlink -f "$1"
    return
  elif readlink -f / >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
    # Maybe you're running a non-Linux system that has a GNU readlink?
    _abspath_mechanism=readlink_f
    readlink -f "$1"
    return
  else
    _abspath_mechanism=_abspath
    _abspath "$1"
    return
  fi

}
```

Comment: (This assumes bash.)

Answer (score 0):

One way is <sup><sub>(I'm hoping for a better version)</sub></sup>

```
olddir=$(pwd)
cd /var/opt/foo
deleteme=$(pwd)
cd $olddir
rm -rf "$olddir"
```

Comment: `readlink` is your friend.